# How to multiply float with integers in C?

Tags: c, integer, operation

When I execute this code it returns me 1610612736

```
void main(){
float a=3.3f;
int b=2;
printf("%d",a*b);
}
```

Why and how to fix this ?

edit : It's not even a matter of integer and float, if i replace int b=2: by float b=2.0f it return the same silly result

Comment: It is a matter of integer and float - see my answer.

Comment: @Carl is right. It may not be a float/int problem with the multiplication itself but it _definitely_ is in the format string.

Comment: The function `printf` is a *varargs* method, with signature `int printf ( const char * format, ... )`.  This means that it takes arbitrary arguments after the first, and it cannot check them at compile time or *cast them to a desired type taken from the format string*.  Your format string  says `%d`, which looks for an `int`.  The expression `a*b` is `float`, which gets converted to `double`.  These types don't even have the same memory size, so the temporary `double` gets physically cut in half and treated as an `int`.  This is not a Solomonic solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Arduino sprintf float not formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27651012/arduino-sprintf-float-not-formatting)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The result of the multiplication of a `float` and an `int` is a `float`.  Besides that, it will get promoted to `double` when passing to `printf`.  You need a `%a`, `%e`, `%f` or `%g` format.  The `%d` format is used to print `int` types.

Editorial note:  The return value of `main` should be `int`.  Here's a fixed program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    float a = 3.3f;
    int b = 2;
    printf("%a\n", a * b);
    printf("%e\n", a * b);
    printf("%f\n", a * b);
    printf("%g\n", a * b);
    return 0;
}
```

and its output:

```
$ ./example 
0x1.a66666p+2
6.600000e+00
6.600000
6.6
```

Comment: Wow, `%a` must be in the running for the "most useless format specifier in a printf role" award :-)

Comment: It's great!  You can transfer (binary) floating point numbers 100% accurately via strings by using it, even to systems that don't use IEEE754.  It preserves all of the bits of precision in a completely unambiguous way.  Users probably don't care to see it, though....

Comment: Now _that's_ a use case I hadn't considered. Good call.

Comment: First time seing %a! Except for debug purpose, i dont really see the use for it.

Answer (score 4):

Alternately, you could also do

```
printf("%d\n", (int)(a*b));
```

and this would print the result you're (kind of) expecting.

You should always explicitly typecast the variables to match the format string, otherwise you could see some weird values printed.