# Arduino C++ sprintf() print "?"

Tags: c++, arduino

```
void loop()
{

  float temperature = dht.readTemperature();
  char test[50];
  sprintf(test, "Temp: %f", temperature);

  Serial.println(temperature); // works fine
  Serial.println(test); // why it prints "?"
  
  delay(300);
}
```

// Output

```
24.10   <== Serial.println(temperature);
?       <== Serial.println(test);
24.10
?
24.10
?
24.10
?
```

Hi. I'm arduino/c newbie. Why print `test` is keep showing `"?"` Am I missing something? When I running the below code in c++ playground, it works fine.

```
float temperature = 23.19;
char test[50];
sprintf(test, "Temp: %f", temperature);
printf("%s", test);        <==== Works fine!
```

Comment: I think this article should help [sprintf in Arduino](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27651012/arduino-sprintf-float-not-formatting)

Comment: @RohanS Thanks a lot! I will close this article